# how can I get different sessionID(windowID) in chrome Incognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome

I open a chrome incognito mode window(ctrl+shift+n), and log in:
https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageAccount

now ,I want login another account, I open a new incognito mode window,

but the new window is already logined for last account,

how can I get different windowsID in chrome Incognito mode?

BTW: google.com only a example, I want login another sites,like stackoverflow.com, so ,I want get a different windowID in new chrome window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it possible to avoid the problem altogether by going to your [Account Settings](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageAccount) and changing "Multiple sign-in" ?

This would allow you to login to multiple accounts in [most Google products](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=181602).

Here's another interesting link: ["Using multiple accounts simultaneously"](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/topic.py?topic=28776) on Google's own online help.

Comment: thanks for help,google.com only a example, I want login another sites,like http://stackoverflow.com, so ,I want get a different windowID in new chrome window,can I?

Comment: @Zenofo Ah, I see. I didn't fully understand your question. I really don't know anything about Chrome development, so I'm sorry but I can't help you much. I find it very strange that two different windows share the same id though.

Comment: Heh, thanks for accepting the answer, if though I didn't real answer your question!